# What is the rationale for using -f in tar

Tags: tar, options

From `man tar`:

> -f, --file ARCHIVE
>   use archive file or device ARCHIVE

Please consider:

```
tar -zxvf myFile.tar.gz
```

As far as I understand, `z` means "gzipped tarball", `x` means "extract", `v` means "verbose output" but about `f` I am not sure.

If we already give the file name `myFile.tar.gz`, why is the `f` argument needed?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves its downvotes. The `-f` option really doesn't make immediate sense to most of us today. Essentially, `tar` is a **t**ape **ar**chiver, and we use `-f` to tell `tar` not to use a tape drive, but a **f**ile instead.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331748/how-to-use-tar-c-without-any-optional-arguments

Comment: See also: [tar without -f option in extraction](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/268273)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the option you use to specify the actual pathname of the archive you would want to work with, either for extracting from or for creating or appending to, etc. If you don't use `-f archivename`, different implementations of `tar` will behave differently (some may try to use a default device under `/dev`, the standard input or output stream, or the file/device specified by an environment variable).

In the command line that you quote,

```
tar -zxvf myFile.tar.gz
```

which is the same as

```
tar -z -x -v -f myFile.tar.gz
```

you use this option with `myFile.tar.gz` as the option-argument to specify that you'd like to extract from a particular file in the current directory.

Consult the  manual for `tar` on your system to see what data stream or device the utility would use if you *don't* use the `-f` option.

The GNU `tar` implementation, for example, has a `--show-defaults` option that will show the default options used by `tar`, and this will probably include the `-f` option (this default may be overridden by setting the `TAPE` environment variable).

Comment: `It's the option you use to specify the actual pathname of the archive you would want to work with, either for extracting from or for creating or appending to, etc.` what is miss is - if the file path was already given, why does `-f` still needed?

Comment: @JohnDoea The archive name is _optional_ and the `-f` option is therefore needed. Various implementations of `tar` uses different defaults for the default archive. On macOS, standard input/output is used, on OpenBSD, the `/dev/rst0` SCSI tape device is used, and GNU `tar` seems to behave differently on different Unixes.  This is why I wrote that last short paragraph (now last _two_ paragraphs).

Comment: @JohnDoea See updates to answer.

Answer (score 4):

So there are many other situations where you need the **`f`** option.

> **-f** *Archive*
>
>     Uses the
>     *Archive*
>     variable as the archive to be read or written. When this flag is not specified, the
>     `tar`
>     command uses a system-dependent default file name of the form
>     `/dev/rmt0`
>     . If the
>     *Archive*
>     variable specified is
>     `-`
>     (minus sign), the
>     `tar`
>     command writes to standard output or reads from standard input. If you write to standard output, the
>     `-c`
>     flag must be used.

From [the tar man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tar.htm).

Examples:
To extract all files in the `/tmp` directory from the archive file on the `/dev/rmt2` tape device and use the time of extraction as the modification time, enter:

```
tar -xm -f/dev/rmt2 /tmp
```

To create a new archive file that contains the `file1` file and pass the archive file to the `dd` command to be written to the `/dev/rmt1` device, enter:

```
tar -cvf - file1 | dd of=/dev/rmt1 conv=sync
```

To archive all directories and complete filenames listed in input list file `infile` into `ar.tar`, enter :

```
tar cvfL ar.tar infile
```

Where `infile` contains the pathnames of files that are to be archived.
To archive files within directories listed in the input list file `infile` into `ar.tar`, enter:

```
tar cvRfL ar.tar infile
```

Comment: the default for GNU `tar` on most Linux distros is to read the archive from stdin, not from `/dev/rmt0`. `tar --show-defaults` shows that: `--format=gnu -f- -b20 ...`. BSD `tar` will use `/dev/st0` by default on linux.

Comment: @mosvy there are several ways to override that default, and even between GNU and BSD the difference means you shouldn't write code that assumes a particular setting. Try `export TAPE=/dev/null` sometime.

Comment: Surely there are ways to override it. The most usual is the `-f` switch ;-)

Comment: Note the very different semantics of the "bundled options" compared to the ordinary (dashed) options: If using "bundled options", as in `tar cvRfL infile`, the pathname argument to `f` is tho next _word_ on the command line, not the `L`.  Had you used `tar -cvRfL infile`, then the argument to `-f` would have been `L`, not the `infile` word on the command line.